# Por que não consigo atualizar o framework?

Tags: iis, framework

Estou tentando instalar um `WebService` no cliente, que é **Windows 7**, mas não estou conseguindo atualizar o framework.

Fiz o download dos framework 4.0 e 4.5 e mesmo assim não aparece para eu ativar. Segue os links

- [Framework 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=17851)
- [Framework 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Segue a imagem do Cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a do meu computador, que é como eu quero que fique:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo: Preciso instalar o framework 4.5 no cliente para que eu consiga rodar o WebService.

Comment: O sistema do cliente tem o *Service Pack 1* instalado?

Comment: Sim, é **Windows 7 Professional com Service Pack 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SDK para rodar fica instalado no computador e pode ser visto na tela de `Desinstalar ou alterar programas`, não tem relação direta com essa tela do recursos. Fora que se você for apenas rodar sua aplicação, por exemplo no IIS, você roda na pool do v4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente instalar estes dois pacotes:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework v4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=17851)
- [Microsoft .NET Framework v4.5.2](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=42642)

Como os updates são cumulativos, você pode executar os dois instaladores sem problemas.